# Close Metro Application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I created a Metro app using the VCL Metropolis UI Application on the File-New menu.

I was surprised that they close the app with:

```
procedure TSplitForm.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
{ CloseButtonClick. }
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

rather than the usual:
procedure TSplitForm.Close1Click(Sender: TObject);
{ Close1Click. }
begin
  Close;
end;
```

I see that Application.Terminate just posts a PostQuitMessage(0);

Is there any difference between close and terminate... and is it necessary to close a Metro app with Application.Terminate?

Comment: Couldn't a 30 second test (or however long it takes you to type `Application.Terminate` and run the app, and then change it to `Close` and run the app) answer this?

Comment: A delphi VCL Application is still a "real" x86 application that is running continuously. Do not confuse a "Metro(polis) UI Application" with a "Metro app" that also runs on WinRT. Your delphi app is still regular desktop application to Windows 8.

Comment: @Ken... Obviously I already know what close does and I also know what Application Terminate does after 25 years of programming since Delphi 1... but I was just wondering why they choose to call Application.Terminate... when most of the time you see Close?

Comment: The only way to get an answer to that is if the EMBT employee who actually wrote the code for the application template happens to stop by and decide to disclose that info. :-) Your question asked if it was necessary to close a Metro app with `Terminate`, and the quick test would have answered that question.

Comment: Trial and error cannot answer the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why not? A Metro UI application uses `TSplitForm = class(TForm)`, where `TForm` is a `Forms.TForm`. There's nothing different about it, so the only question is whether something in the Metro UI changes things. A look at the two forms shows nothing unusual in the way of components used, so there's nothing that affects behavior except the actual code generated. A test shows that `Close` in the main form exits the application as usual. Therefore, there's no functional difference, and a look at the VCL source says that there's no alternate code path for Metro apps.

Comment: Also, to clarify: I'm not the downvoter here. I simply posted a comment asking a question.

Comment: @Ken Now you are talking. That static analysis of the code is what's needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It turned out to be a fun analysis. :-)

Comment: +1. It turned out to be interesting digging into this somewhat to see if I could provide an answer, and I think I worked out why the difference. :-) It did indeed turn out to be something that couldn't quite be figured out by a quick test in 30 seconds. My apologies. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As no one else has offered an answer here...

A Metropolitan UI application uses `TSplitForm = class(TForm)` and `TDetailForm = class(TForm)`, where `TForm` is a `Forms.TForm`. There's nothing different about it, so the only question is whether something in the Metropolitan UI changes things.

A look at the two generated forms in a VCL Metropolitan UI split screen application shows nothing unusual in the way of components used, so there's nothing that affects behavior except the actual code generated. (They're the usual `TPanel`, `TGridPanel`, `TGestureManager`, and other standard VCL components; there's nothing I could see being used that isn't available to any other VCL application.)

A test shows that `Close` in the main form exits the application as usual. Therefore, there's no functional difference. A quick look at the VCL source says that there's no alternate code path for Metropolitan apps.

The only real difference between `Close` and `Application.Terminate` is that `Close` checks to see if it's a modal form or not and whether an `OnCloseQuery` has been assigned and should be called. It then checks to see if it's the main form; if it is, it simply calls `Application.Terminate`. From VCL.Forms, XE4 Update 1, approx. line #6812:

```
if Application.MainForm = Self then Application.Terminate
```

The Metropolitan VCL app template seems to just avoid the usual close processing and directly terminate the application. <strike>There's no indication anywhere of why that would be needed that I can find.</strike>

Actually, after more carefully reviewing the code generated by the Metro VCL template, it looks like the call to `Application.Terminate` is made precisely *because* it skips the normal `Form.Close` processing and immediately exits, which is probably more typical of real Metro applications. (It's also of interest that `CloseButton` isn't actually a button, but is instead a `TImage`.)

The definitive answer to why it uses `Application.Terminate` instead of the usual `Close` may only be determined if someone involved in writing the application template that the IDE generates stops by and tells us. :-)